# How do you insert to Text widget without it triggering the <<Modified>> binding?

Tags: tkinter, textbox, python-3.9

I have a Text widget which I want to automatically insert text to when the window is opened, and then I also want to detect every time that the user modifies the text using the "<< Modified>>" binding. This is not important, but I remember doing the same code earlier and it didn't trigger the "<< Modified>>" binding, but now out of the blue it does, so I'm even more confused. This is the code sample:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
textBox = Text(root, font=("Helvetica", 20))
textBox.pack()

textBox.insert(END, "test")

def on_modifyTextBox():
    print("<<Modified>> bind triggered")

textBox.bind("<<Modified>>", lambda e: on_modifyTextBox())

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
<<Modified>> bind triggered
```

So how do I insert some text to the Text widget by default but then later bind it to << Modified>> without it triggering by itself, but only triggered by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Binding to `<KeyPress>` or `<KeyRelease>` does work technically, and I could just bind to that instead, the only problem with that would be that even when keys that don't modify the text widget are pressed (like Ctrl or Backspace) it is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I found this same issue also. It looks like this is due to the modified flag of the text widget being set to true once you first insert the text. After you insert the 'test' test into the widget, use the following line of code:

```
textBox.edit_modified(False)
```

This should now allow the event to be triggered by the user.